# When removed top div bottom div go to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Hi,

In image when Discount div hide need to special discount go to top. No need to showing space between Base Bill and Special Discount.

[image]

Comment: Show us your code, we can't help you if you don't post something we can work with. We're developers, not wizards. Well... most of us...

Comment: <div class="discountmid">Discount (-) :</div>
                                            <div class="discountright"><span style="font-family:rupee;font-size:11px">R</span>{{dataviewcartitems.billing.discount}}</div><br>
                                            <div class="discountmid">Special Discount (-) :</div>
                                            <div class="discountright"><span style="font-family:rupee;font-size:11px">R</span>{{dataviewcartitems.billing.specialDiscount}}</div>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**, and always make sure that you provide a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** so that we can help you with your code.

Comment: @KesavKrishna Also, please ***edit your post*** rather than posting code in the comments.

Comment: How are you hiding div. Set style = display:none

Answer (score 0):

try removing the br tag. you can also check the html by inspect element and try looking for styles, we cant just look at image/code and tell whats causing problem.